# ElasticSearch + Tire searching only on id field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, elasticsearch, tire

I've looked everywhere but nothing can help me. And I can't figure out what is the problem.

my model

```
class Article
 include Mongoid::Document
 include Mongoid::Timestamps


 include Tire::Model::Search
 include Tire::Model::Callbacks
  mapping do
    indexes :_id, :index => :not_analyzed
    indexes :title
    indexes :body
  end


 def to_indexed_json
   self.to_json
 end

http://localhost:9200/articles/_mapping
{
  "articles": {
    "article": {
      "properties": {
        "$oid": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "body": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "title": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`Article.search 'love'` gives no results,but there are Article with title "love", I've tried to build many requests but nothing works.

all times the same results:

```
"hits"=>{"total"=>0, "max_score"=>nil, "hits"=>[]}}
```

But If I type: `Article.search "cbc267c955464f22d72a0100"`  it gives me article with title: "love"

So it seems to me that tire create indexes only on ID field, regardless mapping indexes on model.

When I recreate indexes

```
Article.index_name
  => "articles" 
Tire.index('articles').delete
  => true 
Article.import
```

my mapping becomes:

```
{
  "articles": {
    "article": {
      "properties": {
        "$oid": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATED**

```
module BSON
  class ObjectId
    def as_json(*args)
      to_s()
    end

    def to_json(*args)
      MultiJson.encode(as_json())
    end
  end
end
```

After implementing this initialize, all seems to work fine

Answer (score 1):

I too encountered such problems while using `tire`. After deleting the index, you can try `Article.create_elasticsearch_index` and `Article.tire.index.import Article.all`.

The `_source` field in your indexed document should have `title`,`id` and `body` included in it, which should make it available for search.

Anyways, `tire` is getting retired as `elasticsearch` gem has now been released.